# How can I Scroll sticky list by clicking on anothor list's items

Tags: android

I just want to Scroll the sticky list to his header by on clicking on button.i have done my sticky list from following website. please help me to scroll the this list.Here is list.please guys help me

https://demonuts.com/android-listview-sticky-header-like-iphone/

Comment: I already provided code link above i have the same code mentioned in above link

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, you should follow the guideline on how to ask. Your call.

Comment: Have you played around with "smoothScrollToPosition(int position)"?

Comment: what mistake did I make in my question.

Comment: Yeah But I am neither using list view nor recycler view so smoothScrollToPosition(int position) possible here

Comment: can you please check it out this link  https://demonuts.com/android-listview-sticky-header-like-iphone/